# actionbar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity that extends `ActionBar`, and am a little confused on how to set the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.

I am confused since I extend actionbar i should not have to create an `ActionBar` object in a class that extends `ActionBar`.

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.R;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class Discover extends ActionbarMenu {




    //get beer details from bundle
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_discover);




    }

    public void openTopBeers(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Discover.class);
        i.setClass(this, BPTopBeers.class);


        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void openTopTastes(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Discover.class);
        i.setClass(this, BPTopTastes.class);


        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void openTopBreweries(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Discover.class);
        i.setClass(this, BPTopBreweries.class);


        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void openTopStyles(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Discover.class);
        i.setClass(this, BPTopStyles.class);


        startActivity(i);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);

        return true;
    }






}
```

Comment: u need to create an action bar object to do this...or try getsupportactionbar.sethomeasupenable(true);

Comment: write it after setContentView(R.layout.activity_discover);

Comment: Since there is nothing in Android named `ActionbarMenu`, you will need to talk to whoever wrote that class.

Comment: ASP why do I need to create an object if it is an actionbarmenu class?

Comment: actionbarmenu class??....never heard of it...if its a library consult the documentation..

Answer (score 0):

You only need the context of the activity to get this method called **setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)**. this method toggles between displaying app icon and custom logo. Also you can define the logo in manifest in attribute `android:logo` of `<application>` and `<activity>` tags and set in theme that you want to use logo instead of app icon in the action bar.